# angular js error : Argument 'questionsCtrl' is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to call a controller when ui loads, but getting below error.

```
angular.js:9778 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'questionsCtrl' is not a function, got string
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/areq?p0=questionsCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%string
    at http://127.0.0.1:60668/js/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (http://127.0.0.1:60668/js/angular.js:1443:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://127.0.0.1:60668/js/angular.js:1453:3)
    at http://127.0.0.1:60668/js/angular.js:7131:9
    at http://127.0.0.1:60668/js/angular-ui-router.js:2797:28
    at nodeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:60668/js/angular.js:6579:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:60668/js/angular.js:5986:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:60668/js/angular.js:5891:30)
    at updateView (http://127.0.0.1:60668/js/angular-ui-router.js:2733:23)
    at http://127.0.0.1:60668/js/angular-ui-router.js:2697:11
```

my code is:

**app.js**

```
 (function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("autoQuote",["ui.router"]);

    app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state("step1", {
              url : "/",
              templateUrl : "step1.html",
              controller: "questionsCtrl"
            })       
            .state("step2", {
              url : "/step2",
              templateUrl : "step2.html",
              controller: "questionsCtrl"
            })
    }]
    );
}());
```

**questionsCtrl.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
    .module("autoQuote")
    .controller("questionsCtrl",["questionsCtrl"]);

    function questionsCtrl() {
        console.log('here in questionsCtrl');
    }

}());
```

Comment: Did you correctly import `questionsCtrl.js` in your HTML page?

Comment: yes, js file include properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer the function when defining the controller.

```
.controller("questionsCtrl", questionsCtrl);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^     : Function reference, not a string
```

The first parameter to the `controller()` is the name of the controller and second is the mappings.

---

I'll suggest to use following min-safe syntax.

```
.controller('questionsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]);
```

To refer to controller function

```
.controller('questionsCtrl', ['$scope', questionsCtrl]);

function questionsCtrl($scope) {
    console.log('In questionsCtrl');
}
```